# Why is 'Bring an umbrella' the correct answer?

Tags: javascript

I am using the Grasshopper app on my phone and I do not understand an example they gave me for if then statements.

They give you the solution because I answered incorrectly, but I do not understand why the solution given is correct.

```
var todayWeather = 'rainy';
var tommorrowWeather = 'cloudy';
if (todayWeather === 'rainy') {
    print('Bring an umbrella');
}
if (todayWeather !== 'rainy') {
    print('Maybe the sun will come out');
}
```

They say the correct answer is 'Bring an umbrella'. But why is this what this code will produce if it is run?

Comment: Which part of the code don't you understand?

Comment: The second if statement I guess. I really do not get how the if statements work and why? Should I just research if statements for Javascript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison

Comment: To print `Maybe the sun will come out` `todayWeather` must be *different*, *not equal* (`!==`) to `rainy`. And today is rainy.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your first line sets `todayWeather` to `rainy`. Your logic then states "If `todayWeather` is `rainy`, print `"Bring an umbrella"`". Please explain what part of this code is holding you up so we can help further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

translating the code to english:

1. create a variable named todayWeather and set it to rainy
2. create a variable named tommorowWeather and set it to cloudy
3. if the variable todayWeather is rainy (true) then
4. print to the screen `Bring an umbrella`
5. (close if conditional)
6. if the variable todayWeather is not rainy (false, because it is set to rainy) then
7. print to the screen `Maybe the sun will come out`
8. (close code conditional)

Note the print statements only execute if the condition is met. 
Also the variable values are never changed by this code after they are set.